# Java postfix operator precedence in expressions with method calls

Tags: java, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

My doubt is why in the following code the output is 2 and 1 respectively?
Is this really OK?
For my perception, the method 'm' should receive the value 1 since it's used the postfix operator on variable 'i' instead of the prefix operator.

```
public class PostfixDoubt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        // why does m receive 2 as argument and not 1?
        i = i++ + m(i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static int m(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Bellow is the bytecode decompiled with javap:

```
public class PostfixDoubt {
  public PostfixDoubt();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: iload_1
       3: iinc          1, 1
       6: iload_1
       7: invokestatic  #16                 // Method m:(I)I
      10: iadd
      11: istore_1
      12: getstatic     #20                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      15: iload_1
      16: invokevirtual #26                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      19: return

  public static int m(int);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #20                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: iload_0
       4: invokevirtual #26                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
       7: iconst_0
       8: ireturn
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operation

```
i++
```

increments the value stored in the `i` variable and returns its previous value. When `i` is re-evaluated to be passed as an argument to

```
m(i)
```

the new, incremented, value is used.

---

```
int i = 1;
i = i++ + m(i);
```

looks like

```
1: 1 (i = 2) + m(i)
2: 1 (i = 2) + m(2)
3: 1 (i = 2) + Whatever value m(2) returns
4: whatever value is the result of that addition
5: that value is assigned to i
```

Comment: Yeah, I understood that, but why when m(i) returns is his result added to 1? If i is already re-evaluated, it should be 2. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like that i is re-evaluated twice. First whem passing it to m(i) and later when it is reassigned to itself with i = <expression>

Comment: @staroski That's what I mean in my edit. It is not re-evaluated. `i++` results in a value (which is pushed on the stack) _and_ `i` is incremented. `m(i)` reaccesses `i` to get its new value. But the `+` operation gets the value of `i++` that was pushed on the stack earlier.

Comment: @staroski If you haven't already, check out the [byte code instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings). What you've just described is basically what happens in byte code.

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you @Sotirios. Sorry I just was not viewing it happening step by step.  The code works exactly like this:  `int variable = 1;` `int postfix_result = variable++;` `int incremented_variable = variable;` `variable = postfix_result + m(incremented_variable);` `System.out.println(variable);`